# Reheating Falafel without drying them out

Tags: reheating

I'm planning to make falafel for lunch break for my colleagues, but I have to prepare them the evening before eating them. The only kitchen appliances available to reheat them are a microwave and an electrical water kettle. Fresh water and all kinds of plates, bowls and dishes are available as well.

What is the best way to reheat falafel without drying them out or making the outer layer tough and rubbery? Should I adjust my recipe in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A damp paper towel draped or loosely wrapping the food will help keep the moisture levels up.

Also, most people reheat at 100%; this is the quickest way to ruin almost all food's texture. Use the microwave at 70% power for a bit longer time. This provides a more even heating and prevents the moisture from essentially boiling out.